# Numerus bei gemeinsamem Adjektiv bei Aufzählung

Tags: adjective, grammatical-number, list

Wie kann man bei einer Konstellation wie ...

> Dies vermeidet unnötigen Aufwand und unnötige Kosten.

... die, nun ja, unnötige Doppelung des Wortes 'unnötig' umgehen? Wären beide Substantive im Plural, hätte ich kein Problem, das Adjektiv einfach vorzuziehen (auch wenn das Ambiguität schafft):

> Dies vermeidet unnötige Aufwände und Kosten.

Aber bei Singular + Plural funktioniert

> Dies vermeidet unnötige Aufwand und Kosten.

m.E. wohl gar nicht. Es ginge wohl noch etwas umständlicher mittels Relativsatz

> Dies vermeidet Aufwand und Kosten, die (beide) unnötig sind.

Aber das zieht die Sache auch schon ganz schön in die Länge.

**Q:** Kann man so etwas doch irgendwie knapp, korrekt und ohne Wiederholung formulieren? Man denke hierbei bitte auch an komplexere Fälle (ersetze beispielsweise "unnötig" durch "voraussichtlich unnötig", "Aufwand" durch "zusätzlichen Aufwand" und "Kosten" durch "hohe Kosten").

**EDIT:** Da einige Kommentare auf die mögliche Redundanz von "unnötig" im Zusammenhang mit "vermeiden" abzielen, denke man vielleicht an andere Beispiele mit derselben Struktur, etwa die Sätze

> Heute gibt es grüne Bohnen und grünen Salat
>
> Herbert ist Autor sozialkritischer englischsprachiger Zeitungsartikel und eines sozialkritischen selten gelesenen Buches

so umzuformulieren, dass die Doppelung von "grün" bzw. "sozialkritisch" vermieden wird.

Comment: Warum sollte "Dies vermeidet unnötige**n** Aufwand und Kosten." nicht gehen?

Comment: Da gibt es dann immer diese Pedanten, die sagen, daß sowieso nur Unnötiges vermieden werden kann, weil man dem Nötigen nicht entgehen kann. – Davon abgesehen: Welches Mißverständnis könnte denn entstehen, wenn ein Leser in *dies vermeidet unnötigen Aufwand und Kosten* das Wort *unnötig* nur auf *Aufwand* und nicht auf *Kosten* bezöge? Also eher ein Scheinproblem.

Comment: @DavidVogt: 1. "Die Deutsche Bahn trägt die Kosten für die Instandhaltung der Gleise, doch der Staat bezahlt den Neubau. Durch die Vernachlässigung der Gleiswartung bis neue Gleisanlagen benötigt werden, vermeidet die Bahn die Investitionen, die für reibungslosen Verkehr nötig sind", "Der Eigentümer wurde gedrängt, endlich die nötige Sanierung anzugehen. Um dies zu vermeiden, hat er beschlossen, das Haus abzureißen". 2. Die Frage gibt nur ein Beispiel. In anderen Fällen (z.B. in wissenschftlichen Fachtexten oder rechtswirksamen Dokumenten) kann sehr viel Information in dieser Auslegung liegen.

Comment: Zu Deinem Edit: Bei Grünen Bohnen ist das "Grüne" kein Adjektiv, sondern Bestandteil des Namens und wird daher sogar groß geschrieben ( https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gartenbohne ), beim (g/G)rünen Salat würde ich es zumindest gefühlt auch so sehen. Daher ist ein "Ausklammern" m.E. gar nicht möglich, und die einzige Option, Doppelung des "grün" zu vermeiden, bestünde in der eher humorvollen Formulierung *Heute gibt es grüne Bohnen und ebensolchen Salat*

Answer (score 3):

Tausch die Substantive:

> Das vermeidet unnötige Kosten und Aufwand.

Wenn man den Aufwand vermeiden kann, dann ist das unnötig damit schon impliziert, so dass nicht wichtig ist, ob ein Hörer/Leser das unnötig auf beide Größen bezieht.

> Das vermeidet vorraussichtlich unnötige Kosten und Aufwand.
>
> Das vermeidet vorraussichtlich unnötige Kosten und zusätzlichen Aufwand.
>
> Das vermeidet vorraussichtlich unnötige, hohe Kosten und zusätzlichen Aufwand.

Je mehr Variation auftritt, um so eher bezieht man das "unnötige" nur auf das unmittelbar folgende Substantiv. Semantisch bleibt der Satz aber gleich, da man ja offenbar Aufwand und Kosten vermeiden kann, diese also unnötig sind.

@Edit:
Den grünen Bohnen und gleichfarbigem Salat sieht und hört man nicht an, dass es Verkürzungen sein können, wenn man

> Heute gibt es grünen Salat und Bohnen.

schreibt. Die Dopplung von Grün stört aber bei

> Heute gibt es grüne Bohnen und grünen Salat.

auch nicht. Man könnte das Grün ausklammern, aber das wird nicht kürzer sein:

> - Heute gibt es grünen Salat und gleichfarbige Bohnen.
> - Heute gibt es grünen Salat und ebensolche Bohnen.
> - Heute gibt es Salat und Bohnen, beide von grüner Farbe.

Grün ist aber nicht einfach ein Adjektiv bei Bohnen und Salat, sondern Teil des Namens.

> Heute gibt es Grünen Salat und Grüne Bohnen.

Kommen wir zum Sozialkritischen:

> Herbert ist Autor sozialkritischer englischsprachiger Zeitungsartikel und eines sozialkritischen selten gelesenen Buches.

Eine Attributliste - also wieder mit Komma trennen:

> Herbert ist Autor sozialkritischer, englischsprachiger Zeitungsartikel und eines sozialkritischen, selten gelesenen Buches.

Ob das Buch auch englischsprachig ist wissen wir auch nicht. Manchmal kann man mit Wissenslücken überraschend gut leben. Aber wenn wir fanatisch Redundanzfreiheit anstreben hält uns nichts auf:

> Herbert ist Autor sozialkritischer, englischsprachiger Zeitungsartikel und eines selten gelesenen Buches gleicher Haltung.

Comment: Könnte man mit dem gleichen Argument nicht "unnötig" ganz weglassen? Wenn die Kosten vermieden werden können, sind sie doch auch implizit unnötig?

Comment: @jarnbjo Unmittelbar wären sie zunächst eher vermeidbar als unnötig. Ob das einen Unterschied macht, sei dahingestellt :)

Comment: @jambo So ganz unnötig ist die Ergänzung "unnötig" vielleicht doch nicht. Umsatzsteuer ist legal betrachtet ein "nötiger" Kostenanteil - aber er lässt sich durch Schwarzarbeit "vermeiden"

Comment: @jarnbjo: Oft erzeugt man eine gewisse Redundanz, um einen Sachverhalt zu betonen. Vielleicht ist auch strittig, ob das zu zahlende Gut oder der zu leistende Aufwand nötig oder unnötig ist und man möchte so seine Position klarstellen.

Comment: Fehlt da im dritten Beispiel nicht ein Komma? `das verhindert [...] unnötige, hohe Kosten [...]`. Aufeinanderfolgende Adjektiven (die sich auf dasselbe Substantiv beziehen) werden doch durch Kommas getrennt, solange gas letzte Adjektiv nicht fest mit dem Substantiv verbunden ist (z.B.`eine schüchterne graue Maus`). Hier ist das Komma tatsächlich entscheident, da es sonst genausogut ein Adverb mit Tippfehler (`unnötig hohe Kosten`) sein könnte.

Comment: @hajef: Danke, korrigiert.

Answer (score 0):

Da Kosten und Aufwand oft zusammenhängen, hätte ich den Vorschlag:

> Dies vermeidet unnötigen Aufwand und daraus entstehende Kosten.

oder

> Dies vermeidet unnötigen Aufwand und Folgekosten.

Comment: Du könntest eine Staumauer mit Freiwilligen bauen, die 2m hoch werden soll - ein anderer schlägt 3m vor. Mit Aufwand kann die Arbeit gemeint sein, mit Kosten die Materialbeschaffung. Aus der Arbeit entstünden dann keine Kosten. Folgekosten sind noch mal was anderes, etwa Unterhalt.

Answer (score 0):

> Kann man so etwas doch irgendwie knapp, korrekt und ohne Wiederholung formulieren?

Mir ist nichts bekannt, wie sich diese Worte nur einmal, aber erkennbar auf sowohl Aufwand als auch Kosten bezogen in einen Satz fassen lassen.
Am besten formuliert man solche Sätze tatsächlich um.

Im erste Beispiel etwa:

> Dies vermeidet unnötige zusätzliche Belastungen, wie Arbeitsaufwand und Kosten.*

#### Fester Bestandteil eines Namens

> Heute gibt es grüne Bohnen und grünen Salat.

In diesen Fällen ist "grün" keine nähere Beschreibung, sondern Teil eines festen Begriffs. Grüne Bohnen sind eine spezielle Art von Bohnen, genauso wie grüner Salat eine bestimmte Art von Salat beschreibt.
Daher sagt der Satz

> Es gibt grüne Bohnen und Salate.

selbst mit zweimal Mehrzahl nur aus, dass es 1. grüne Bohnen und 2. irgendwelche Salate gibt. Hier bleibt nichts anderes übrig als zweimal "grün" zu erwähnen.
Mit Mehrzahl und Einzahl entfernen sich die Begriffe noch weiter voneinander.

#### Weiteres Beispiel

> Herbert ist Autor sozialkritischer englischsprachiger Zeitungsartikel und eines sozialkritischen selten gelesenen Buches.

Da wird es wirklich interessant.
Formulieren wir diesen Satz so um, dass er zweimal Mehrzahl enthält und verkürzen ihn:

> Herbert ist Autor sozialkritischer englischsprachiger Zeitungsartikel und selten gelesener Bücher.

Die Phrase "selten gelesen" lässt sowohl für "sozialkritisch", also auch "englischsprachig" keinen Bezug mehr zu den Büchern übrig. Mit der Einzahl wäre das noch weniger gegeben.
Auch hier bleibt am besten nur eine Umformulierung:

> Herbert hat mehrere Zeitungsartikel und ein selten gelesenes Buch verfasst, alle in englischer Sprache und mit sozialkritischem Inhalt.

Answer (score 0):

Die Fragen sind für mich 'unbefriedigend', weil kontextlos. Das ist hier beliebt, führt jedoch stets zu Rätselraten: Was soll eigentlich gemeint sein? Indessen soll hier nur, soweit ich es verstanden habe, eine Generallösung für ein Unterproblem aus einer bestimmten Sorte von grammatischen Konstrukten gefunden werden: *Wie ließe sich für [A + N (Singular)] + [(A + N (Plural)] bei gleichlautendem A die Wiederholung des A vermeiden?* Beispiele dafür kann man füglich konstruieren, aber ob sich einem so etwas auch beim Reden oder Schreiben tatsächlich als Problem stellen würde?

#### Zum Wort '*Aufwand*'

'*Aufwand*' hat nach [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Aufwand) Bedeutung 3 und nach [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Aufwand) Bedeutung c) bereits einen Bedeutungsanteil '*übertrieben, zuviel des Guten*', wörtlich dort "unnötig". Eine Redundanz fällt so nicht erst bei '*vermeiden*', sondern bereits bei '*Aufwand*' an.

Zweiterhin ist mit *Aufwand* ziemlich oft die finanzielle Seite gemeint; '*Kosten und Aufwand*' ist ein wenig wie '*Äpfel und Obst*'. Vielleicht ist es sinnvoll, darauf hinzuweisen, dass mit '*Aufwand*' jedenfalls andere als Kostenaufwendungen gemeint sein sollen: Zeit-, Organisations-, Bürokratie-, Kommunikations- ... -aufwand. Dies ließe sich als '*Kosten und **sonstiger** Aufwand*' bewerkstelligen, so wie man auch sagen könnte '*Äpfel und weiteres Obst*'.

Nebenbei fühlt man sich an Begriffe wie 'Kosten' und 'Aufwendungen' aus der Finanzbuchhaltung erinnert und fragt sich, ob das vielleicht gemeint sein soll, denn im Alltag könnte ein Begriff wie 'Gesamtaufwand' genügen. Nur in der FiBu gibt es einen Kostenbegriff, der von den Aufwendungen definitorisch streng getrennt wird; er hat dann auch mit dem Alltagsbegriff 'Kosten' nichts zu tun hat.

Schließlich wäre zu bedenken, dass, was dem einen als Geldverschwendung erscheinen mag, sich dem anderen als durchaus sinnvolle Investition darstellen kann, oder anders gesagt: '*Unnötig*' ist sehr relativ. In dieser Richtung weitergedacht gelangt man zur Überlegung: Eigentlich geht es doch nur darum, Kosten überhaupt zu vermeiden, sie klein zu halten, und kommt dann zu

> Auf diese Weise lassen sich Kosten und sonstiger Aufwand eingrenzen.

#### '*grün*'

Adjektive können sich mit Substantiven zu einem Gesamtbegriff verbinden. Auf die '*grünen Bohnen*' trifft das insofern zu, als sie zumindest im Gegensatz zu den gelben (Salat-)Bohnen auch '*grüne Bohnen*' genannt werden. Ob das für den '*grünen Salat*' auch gilt? Meinem Gefühl nach nicht, vielleicht irre ich mich. Mit '*grünem Salat*' ist aber **nicht jeder '*grüne*' Salat** gemeint (z.B. Grüne-Bohnen-Salat, Gurkensalat, Löwenzahnsalat ...), sondern ein Standard-Blattsalat. Ich würde darunter Kopfsalat verstehen, vielleicht auch Feld-/Ackersalat, bei Endivien kämen mir schon Zweifel, weil er teils gelb sein kann und weil er einen charakteristischen Eigengeschmack hat. Wie auch immer erscheint mir der Status von '*grün*' in beiden Verbindungen ein anderer zu sein, weswegen ich ihn ungeachtet von der Singular-/Pluralfrage nicht ausklammern würde. Trotzdem ist die Wiederholung unschön. Das liegt vielleicht wieder an ihrer Konstruiertheit: Warum soll es wichtig sein, auf dem Salat als '*grünem Salat*' zu bestehen, wenn man doch problemlos von '*Blattsalat*' sprechen kann, und überhaupt: Was soll das für eine Mahlzeit sein, "grüne Bohnen und grüner Salat"?? Bohnensalat und dazu ein anderer Salat, noch dazu Kopfsalat - wo bleibt da die Sättigungsbeilage? Oder Bohneneintopf mit Blattsalat? Fazit: Insofern bereits die kulinarische Kombination leichte Irritationen auslöst, geht der sprachliche Schönheitsfehler von '*grünen Bohnen mit grünem Salat*' damit konform und in Ordnung.

#### '*sozialkritisch*'

Die Kombination mehrerer attributiver Adjektive mit einem Nomen ist nicht trivial. Sie treten auf als (eine (*arme* (*alte Frau*))), oder ((*kurze*,) (*leichte*) Sommerkleidchen)) oder ((*heruntergesetzte*, (*weil abgelaufene*)) *Lebensmittel*) und in anderen Schachtelungen, aber nicht als (eine (*schwarze* (*große Katze*))) [korrekterweise sollte es sich um eine '*(große (schwarze Katze))*' handeln]. In dem Beispiel mit Herbert geht es darum, dass er mehrfach auf Englisch publiziert hat. Sollten dies tatsächlich Zeitungen gewesen sein, dann ist es recht wahrscheinlich, dass jeweils die ganze Zeitung englischsprachig ist und dass sie für den englischen Sprachraum veröffentlicht wird. Es mag hier und da in der FAZ oder in der ZEIT einen englischsprachigen Artikel geben, aber der ist dann eher nicht sozialkritisch. Hingegen gibt es durchaus in deutschen Fachzeitschriften englischsprachige Artikel, aber es sollen ja Zeitungen sein. Das ist eine erste, und zwar sachliche Schwierigkeit.

Vielleicht könnte man einfacher von 'sozialkritischen Zeitungsartikeln in englischer Sprache' und von einem 'selten gelesenen sozialkritischen Buch' (Reihenfolge!) sprechen, zur Not vielleicht auch von einem 'selten gelesenen, weil sozialkritischen Buch'.

All das ist recht kompliziert, zumal wenn es von einem überdachenden 'sozialkritisch' zusammengehalten werden soll. Wieso nicht einfach:

> Seine sozialkritischen Standpunkte vertrat er in englischsprachigen
>   Zeitungen und in einem - selten gelesenen - Buch [*dessen Titel man
>   normalerweise an dieser Stelle nennen würde*].

Mein Fazit: Wenn sich bei der Planung des weiteren Satzverlaufs eine kritische Stelle mit Adjektivwiederholung anbahnt, wird ein geübter Schreiber vermutlich die Planung ändern und den Satz so umbauen, dass das Problem entfällt. Das dürfte praktisch immer möglich sein, vorausgesetzt, es handelt sich um pragmatisch plausible Kommunikationsabsichten.

Ich für meinen Teil gehe immer stark von der pragmatischen Seite und von realen Sprachereignissen aus, und ich frage bei präsentierten "Beispielen": Kann es einen solchen Satz oder eine solche Kommunikationsabsicht überhaupt geben? Ziemlich oft komme ich zu der Ansicht, dass hier vorgestellte Beispielssätze Kunstgebilde oder dass die dahinter liegenden Formulierungs'bedarfe' unplausibel sind.

Comment: Spätestens, wenn man sich bewusst macht, dass diese "Problemklasse" nicht nur bei bei zwei Numeri sondern auch bei verschiedenen Genera auftritt, ist ihre Häufigkeit und Unvermeidbarkeit meines Erachtens nach klar. Beispielsweise verlangt "Gendergerechte Sprache" i.d.R. nach einer strikten Trennng der Genera nach Sexus oder Gender der bezeichneten Personen. Um dieser Problemklasse ganz gerecht zu werden, muss man vielleicht die Frage allgemeiner fassen aber so oder so tritt die Formel `[A + N1] + [A + N2] -?> A + [N1 + N2]` häufiger auf und es sollten dabei dieselben Regeln greifen.

Comment: @hajef: Berechtigter Einwand, die Genderfraktion macht in der Tat ähnliche Turnübungen. Aus denen möchte ich selbst mich weitgehend raushalten, es ist mir energetisch zu aufwändig und lässt sich auch nicht komplett durchhalten, es sei denn um den Preis von (je nachdem) Spontanverständlichkeit und so etwas wie Sprachästhetik. Ich bin ziemlich sicher, dass die meisten Deutschsprecher das nicht gut leisten können, weil  man dafür seine Sätze wie beim Schachspiel mit viel Vorlauf strategisch planen muss, und das ist in der Regel eine Überforderung.

Answer (score -1):

Ich habe dazu einen verwandten [Artikel im Duduen](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/%E2%80%9Esowohl-als-auch%E2%80%9C-%E2%80%93-Singular-oder-Plural-Auf%C2%ADz%C3%A4hlung%C2%ADen) gefunden, der sich aber auf Subjekte die Beugung ihrer Verben bezieht. Demnach können Aufzählungen unter bestimmten Umständen aber eben nicht immer als gemeinsamer Plural verstanden werden. Nun ist nicht ganz eindeutig, ob und wie diese Regeln auf Objekte anzuwenden sind, aber wenn wir davon ausgehen, dass sie eins zu eins übertragen werden, kann man hier je nach Auslegung und Aufbau den zusammenfassenden Plural, den Numerus eines der beiden Teile auf beide beziehen oder den jeweils den Numerus eines Teils nur auf diesen Teil beziehen.

Man verwendet keinen zusammenfassenden Plural wenn:

- Beide Substantive ohne Konjunktion verbunden sind ("Dies vermeidet unnötigen Aufwand, Kosten" oder "Das vermeidet unnötige Kosten, Aufwand", "unnötig" bezieht sich in beiden Fällen klar auf beide Substantive)
- Beide Substantive durch Konjunktion *und* Verb getrennt sind ("Der Aufwand ist unnötig sowie die Kosten" oder "Die Kosten sind unnötig sowie der Aufwand)
- Eine Aufzählung in Tabellenform vorliegt ("Unnötiges: Aufwand, Kosten")
- Ein Substantiv das andere mit einschließt ("Unnötiger Aufwand und finanzielle Aufwendungen"
- Wenn "nicht nur - sondern auch" oder "sowohl- als auch" verwendet werden ("Dies vermeidet sowohl unnötigen Aufwand als auch Kosten" oder "Dies verhindert sowohl unnötige Kosten als auch Aufwand")

In allen anderen Fällen verwendet man den zusammenfassenden Plural. Z.B. "Dies verhindert unnötige Aufwand und Kosten", was etwas holprig klingt aber korrekt ist und im Gegensatz zu "unnötige Kosten und Aufwand" in jedem Fall klar zeigt, dass sich das Adjektiv auf beide Substantive bezieht - Wobei ich in diesem Beispiel auch letzteres wählen würde.

Comment: Einige Korrekturen habe ich vorgenommen. Im letzten Absatz "Dies verhindert unnötige Aufwand und Kosten" habe ich gezögert, weil mein spontaner Korrekturwunsch "Dies verhindert unnötigen Aufwand und Kosten" Aufwand nicht im Plural sieht und ich nicht weiß, was Du genau sagen willst. Bei "unnötige Wege und Kosten" wäre beides im Plural.

Comment: Ja es war genau so gemeint und ist meines Wissens nach korrekt (wenn auch - wie gesagt - unschön). Aber es ist halt die Variante, die am dichtesten an der Ursprungsformulierung steht, (vermutlich) korrekt ist und keine weiteren Worte einfügt.

Comment: Nun, es ist sicher nicht korrekt. "Die unnötigen Kosten, der unnötige Aufwand". Das kann man nicht zusammenziehen, so wie auch nicht: "Wir haben kleine Katzen und Papagei."

Comment: Es geht dabei um die Frage, ob man im Deutschen eine Aufzählung zu einem gedachten Plural zusammenfassen kann. Wenn ja ist es korrekt, wenn nein sicher nicht, da die Wahrheit ein entschiedenes "jain" ist, habe ich mal provokant die unschöne Formulierung gebildet und warte auf die Regel, die sie mir verbietet. Bei Verben geht es garantiert (siehe Link) "Die Kratzsteine brauchen Katze(n) und Papagei".

Comment: "Die Kratzsteine brauchen Katzen und Papageien.", "Die Kratzsteine brauchen die Katzen und der Papagei." oder "Die Kratzsteine brauchen meine Katzen und mein Papagei." Nicht: "Die Kratzsteine brauchen meine Katzen und Papagei."

Comment: Ist das noch aufrichtiges Unverständnis oder schon bewusste Provokation? Vor allem reden wir offensichtlich aneinander vorbei. Kann man die Regeln für Verben, die sich auf mehrere Nomen beziehen, auch auf Artikel und Pronomen anwenden? (Denn "brauchen meine Katzen und Papageien" geht) Ich weiß es nicht aber solange ich keine gegenteilige Regel verlinkt bekomme, ist das alles nur eine fade Scheinargumentation. Es klingt falsch. Es ist nicht üblich. Was hat das damit zu tun, ob es theoretisch erlaubt und damit formell richtig ist?